# Reading a checkpointed RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I'm attempting to pre-compute my data such that I can pull an RDD from a checkpoint. However, I'm finding that upon running the same job twice the system is simply recreating the RDD from scratch.

Here is the code I'm implementing to create the checkpoint:

```
  def checkpointTeam(checkpointDir:String) ={
    sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(checkpointDir)
    val a = ObjectsTable.readAsRDD(sparkContext, Some("5507424...")).persist() //read from HBase
    a.checkpoint()
    a.count()
  }
```

edit: here is the code that creates my sparkContext

```
val sparkContext = {
      val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName(appName.getOrElse(jobName))

        .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")


      sparkConf.setMaster(EnvConfig.sparkMaster)

      Option(System.getenv("SPARK_HOME")).foreach(sparkConf.setSparkHome)

      sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")    
      sparkConf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
      sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.am.memory", "14g")
      sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.am.cores", "4")
      sparkConf.set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions","-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode")
      sparkConf.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode")
      sparkConf.set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.4")
      sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "4000")

      sparkConf.set("spark.locality.wait.process","120000")

      new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    }

    sparkContext.addSparkListener(new StatsReportListener())

    log.info("Initialized SparkContext")

    sparkContext
  }
```

Comment: Show us the code running the `SparkContext`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov added

Comment: One who is not using streaming they can always use localcheckpoints to save the dataframe .

Comment: persist and the checkpoint is two different things.
in your code you have used the persist method, it saved the data in the storage.
While checkpointing saves the data at the checkpointed directory.

Answer (score -1):

If you working with streaming context just use StreamingContext.getOrCreate, see documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#how-to-configure-checkpointing

if it's not streaming - you can control when you save your rdd in your batch job and to where, so you'll be able to load it exactly from same place(usually in batchs you don't need to checkpoint unless you have huge lineage, but then it's not for the sake of saving data, but rather for truncating DAG)

Comment: Hi Igor, I've been able to find the files where the data is saved, but it appears to be serialized and I'm not sure how to deserialize it. Would you know how to reload the info? Also I'm not using streaming.

Comment: Hi, not sure what format spark uses to serialize data while checkpointing. Why can't you use something like saveAsObjectFile to write and objectFile to load back?(http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets)

Comment: "you'll be able"--- how? ;)